# How to Change tkcalendar date?

Tags: python, tkcalendar

this is probably a really simple question, but I can't seem to find the answer.

But how do I go about changing the date of a tkcalendar calendar without user input?

Right now I am creating a new calendar every time my program loops to certain screen and I feel that this is inefficient.

**Example:**

---

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the [documentation](https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Calendar.html#tkcalendar.Calendar.selection_set), the `Calendar` class has a `.selection_set()` method to change the selected date. It takes in argument the date to be selected in the form of a `datetime.date`, a `datetime.datetime` or a string formated according to the locale used in the calendar.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkcalendar as tkc
from datetime import date

root = tk.Tk()
cal = tkc.Calendar(root, year=1900, month=11, day=11)
cal.pack()

tk.Button(root, text="Change date", command=lambda: cal.selection_set(date(2001, 1, 18))).pack()
```

Alternatively, you can connect a `StringVar` to the calendar through the `textvariable` option and use it to get and set the selected date:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkcalendar as tkc
from datetime import date

root = tk.Tk()
datevar = tk.StringVar(root, "11/11/1990")
cal = tkc.Calendar(root, textvariable=datevar, locale="en_US")
cal.pack()

tk.Button(root, text="Change date", command=lambda: datevar.set("01/18/2001")).pack()
```

Comment: Ah thanks for that, that answers my question perfectly! I gave that documentation a look so I don't know how I missed it.
Thanks again!